# Can you use objects instead of arrays with ng-option and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I am using ng-options to populate items in a select menu.

```
ng-options="i.option for i in week.items"
```

With an array to populate the items.

```
week.items = [
  {
    'option': '8 Week Single Transformation | 2 Payments of $198.50',
    'price' : 198.5
  },
  ....
  {
    'option': '8 Week Partner Transformation | $597',
    'price' : 597
  }];
```

Is it possible to use an object instead of an array, or is ng-options only set up to work with arrays?

Comment: Of course it is possible. Did you read documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions ?

Comment: c'mon man.... read the docs before asking something like this

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so. The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) say it as well. Here is an example object

```
$scope.letters = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2
   };
```

And the HTML

```
ng-options="letter for (letter, value) in letters"
```